# Elasticsearch Query 30Day Price Difference

Tags: elasticsearch

I currently have an elasticsearch indexs for a product that spans a year each index separated by month (i think, could be by year if i dont have as much data as i think i do). Each day a process grabs all the prices of these products and puts them into elasticsearch. I am trying to build a query that can give me the percent change within the last 30days of each product.

Example...

```
{
  "timestamp": "2019-09-18T02:38:51.417Z",
  "productId": 1,
  "marketPrice": 5.00,
  "lowPrice": 4.30
},
{ 
  "timestamp": "2019-08-30T02:38:51.417Z", (THIS SHOULD BE IGNORED)**
  "productId": 1,
  "marketPrice": 100.00,
  "lowPrice": 200.15
},
{
  "timestamp": "2019-08-18T02:38:51.417Z",
  "productId": 1,
  "marketPrice": 10.00,
  "lowPrice": 2.15
},
{
  "timestamp": "2019-09-18T02:38:51.417Z",
  "productId": 2,
  "marketPrice": 2.00,
  "lowPrice": 1.00
},
{
  "timestamp": "2019-08-18T02:38:51.417Z",
  "productId": 2,
  "marketPrice": 3.00,
  "lowPrice": 2.00
}
```

Result Example

```
{
  "productId": 1,
  "marketPriceChangeWithin30Days": 200%,
  "lowPriceChangeWithin30Days": 200%
},
{
  "productId": 2,
  "marketPriceChangeWithin30Days": 150%,
  "lowPriceChangeWithin30Days": 200%
}
```

** The (THIS SHOULD BE IGNORED) is because the only two values that should be compared are the latest timestamp and the closest timestamp that is around 30days in the past.

The query would then return the product id 1 and 2 with the percent changed in the result as shown in the example response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leverage the [`derivative` pipeline aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-derivative-aggregation.html) to achieve exactly what you expect:

```
POST /sales/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "sales_per_month": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "timestamp",
        "interval": "month"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "marketPrice": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "marketPrice"
          }
        },
        "lowPrice": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "lowPrice"
          }
        },
        "marketPriceDiff": {
          "derivative": {
            "buckets_path": "marketPrice"
          }
        },
        "lowPriceDiff": {
          "derivative": {
            "buckets_path": "lowPrice"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Given your updated requirements, I'd suggest using the [`serial_diff` pipeline aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-serialdiff-aggregation.html) with a lag of 30 days:

```
POST /sales/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "timestamp": {
        "gte": "now-31d",
        "lte": "now"
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "products": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "productId",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "histo": {
          "date_histogram": {
            "field": "timestamp",
            "interval": "day",
            "min_doc_count": 0
          },
          "aggs": {
            "marketPrice": {
              "avg": {
                "field": "marketPrice"
              }
            },
            "lowPrice": {
              "avg": {
                "field": "lowPrice"
              }
            },
            "30d_diff_marketPrice": {
              "serial_diff": {
                "buckets_path": "marketPrice",
                "lag": 30
              }
            },
            "30d_diff_lowPrice": {
              "serial_diff": {
                "buckets_path": "lowPrice",
                "lag": 30
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is closer to what I am looking for. But this is giving me the total sum of those 2 values over the course of the month. Where as I want to compare the latest timestamp of each product with 30 days ago value.

Comment: I updated my question a little bit, hopefully showing the expected result will clear up what I am trying to do! Thanks :)

Comment: This is starting look perfect! I have one question, is it safe to assume I should change the date histogram to month since I only care about that first value?

Comment: The `serial_diff` pipeline aggregation works on the number of buckets, so if you change to month, you need to change the lag as well.

Comment: Ahh i see whats going on here now. Ok cool, thanks this makes a lot more sense now.